# Problem with multiple displays on Lenovo P43s and ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Gen 2 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad P43s where I connect my display (Dell) through a ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2:

https://support.lenovo.com/dk/en/solutions/pd500265

Everything works fine until I lock my computer. When I then try to unlock it my external display does not turn on again. At least not most of the times, sometimes it works and other times it does not. And sometimes I  can get it to work by turning the external display off/on or disconnect/reconnect the dock.

This is very frustrating especially at work where I need to switch to different locations that has different displays.

I see the same problem on all displays I connect to through HDMI  displayport.

I have found:

https://www.displaylink.com/downloads

which I have tried to install but it does nothing. Not sure if I need to run some configuration after I have installed it??

Any suggestions?

I would rather not have to exchange my Lenovo/Ubuntu for an Apple/OSX setup to get this to work.

Also I am on the latest version on the dock firmware: **3.1.67.0**

[image]

And I don't have the problem on Windows 10 (I have a multiboot/grub setup).

And apperantly I am not alone:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Thunderbolt-3-Dock-Issue-with-Monitors-not-turning-on-after-wakeup-from-sleep/m-p/4304363

Comment: All those responses on your lenovo link were for Windows, so you are lucky.  The firmware updates (your 3.1.66) seems to (cause | not fix) the problem. Take a look at https://egpu.io/forums/thunderbolt-linux-setup/ for a more linux specific forum.  I use a Lenovo egpu off an expresscard, and avoided all problems by keeping my firmware at a known good version and not updating to the latest.

Comment: Ok but what do you suggest then? As I understand it’s not possible to downgrade firmware for the dock once it’s been upgraded

Comment: You already have a working Windows solution, so no need to downgrade (done by replacing the dock :^( ) Check out the egpu linux forum, others may have had similar problems and have solutions. Lenovo's firmware updates (on my machine) seem to squeeze down necessary PCI buffer (?) space for larger video cards, so there are workarounds for moving from a 32 bit addr space to a 36 bit one (google the TOLUD memory problem) . I really didn't look very hard at any thunderbolt forums, since I'm off an expressCard/PCI slot.

Comment: Well the solution is not windows, I am primarily using Linux/Ubuntu so that’s where I need it to work. And even though I get a replacement it’s not going to be ok never to upgrade the firmware. And I am probably not going to write my own driver/firmware for the dock so basically as of now it seems I need to consider dell, Mac or some other brand

Comment: Try your dock on any new machine before comiting to purchase, at least one user on your Lenovo link had previously had a Dell with the same problem (and so tried Lenovo;^( ). Good Luck.

Comment: @ubfan1 - very "helpful" advice. :^/

Comment: @u123 - any update? did you manage to find any help?